# Unusual icon on iPad screen

Tags: ipad, icon

How do I remove 3 arrows in a black rectangle on the top right of my iPad screen? This is not an app and does not move.

Comment: Hello and welcome Ask Different. I am sure you will find the site has much to offer. I recommend you read the [tour] page. Can you please [edit] the question and attach a picture of the icon?

Comment: Along with what @DaniilManokhin suggested, it may be helpful to include details on which model iPad you are using as well as which version of iOS it is running.

Comment: Is it a screen protector? Can you see it on screenshots? Can you post a picture?

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check is if you have enabled  Assistive Touch or Switch Control.

These are enabled and disabled in the Settings app:
 -> General -> Accessibility

[image]

Comment: The assistive touch icon is a white circle in a black rectangle and doesn’t match the OP’s description

Comment: I didn't say it has top be exactly Assistive Touch, just posted a suggestion where to look at.

Comment: What should I do in a situation like this, when I want to help the user solve their problem, but there's no way of exactly answering the question without having a further conversation with the user?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. @Yarik You can always put up an answer that will teach other people something. Even if the OP doesn't want this - others will find it useful and vote it up. Even wrong answers help teach and others learn. Knowing what it's not is useful. When a question is unclear - it's best to make a comment just like Daniil did - so both your answer and his comment are welcome and good for helping out when a question is vague. We have [help] and [meta] for more information on how the site is run. Thanks for answering! +1

Comment: @Yarik You can ask for clarity or explanation via the Comments, where we're now talking. Because you're not sure your explanation will solve the OP's problem, your info could have been presented in a Comment as well.